# pandasのデータフレームをスプレッドシートへ反映したい

Tags: python, pandas, google-spreadsheet

スプレッドシートのAPIを用いてデータフレームをスプレッドシートの最下部に追記したいのですが、うまい方法はなにかあるでしょうか。

#### やりたいこと

データフレームをスプレッドシートの最下部に追加したい

**コード:**

```
import pandas as pd
import gspread
import csv
import json
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe

df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')

SPREADSHEET = '対象スプレッドシート'
WORKSHEET = 'Sheet1'

sh = gc.open_by_key(SPREADSHEET)
sh.values_append(WORKSHEET,{'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'},{'values': df.values.tolist()})
```

dfには対象のデータフレームが入っております。

**エラー内容:**

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\n.0, 13500, 50490.0, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, \n                    ^', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}
```

スプレッドシートのJSONファイルも正しく指定・格納されている状態です

**データフレームイメージ:**

Aさん　30歳　男性
Bさん　25歳　男性

色々調べたのですが、同様のエラーが見当たらずご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: import等も含めた他の人が問題を再現できる程度のスクリプト全体と、表示されたエラーメッセージを略さず全てを提示してみてください。[Add data after the last filled line of Google Sheets, with gspread python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69511235/9014308), [How to format pandas dataframe into google sheets api properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66573567/9014308), [Append rows to Google Sheets using gspread or googleapiclient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59860831/9014308), [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: import 周りを追記しました。
エラー内容は省略しておらず、この表記になっているのでこれが全文になります。

Comment: `df.values.tolist()` としている部分を `df.to_json()` に変更するとどうなりますか？

Comment: `df.to_json()` にした場合は`ValueError: DataFrame index must be unique for orient='columns'.`が返ってきます。

Answer (score 1):

colabでなら簡単です。ローカル pythonから直接使ったことがないため比較はできないけれど
デメリット

- pythonのバージョンが少し低い
- ローカルデータがある場合, google-drive経由などになること

```py
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

import pandas as pd
worksheet = gc.open('タイトル').sheet1

df = pd.DataFrame({'名前': ['A', 'B'], '年齢': [30, 25], '性別': ['男', '男']})
display(df)
worksheet.append_rows([df.columns.values.tolist()] +df.values.tolist())
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
こちらも試してみます。